# how do I install the traceroute functionality from busybox programmatically

Tags: android, busybox, traceroute

I am currently working on implementing traceroute functionality in android and for that I need some help.

I aksed question on this on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15804499/implement-traceroute-functionality-in-android).

And in answer user of suggested me to do following :

**The [busybox](https://code.google.com/p/busybox-android/) utility includes traceroute. You can run busybox on your device without rooting your phone by following this [youtube tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L_bVC0x4l-g). You should then be able to use the first code segment you posted to query traceroute from within your app. Of course, you will need to make sure that you use the correct path when calling traceroute.**

Now you will think why I am asking same again but I watched video and coudnt understand how to make it work in my application as If I want to make app like this how can I install busybox apk in user's device.

So please show me some code so that I can understand it.

Comment: 1) You cannot make your app install an other app automatically. 2) There is no way to implement traceroute functionality without additional tricks from within an app. 3) What you want precisely is not possible; the answer just pointed you in a direction which makes it possible even though it does not fulfill all your requirements.

Comment: This question should be "how do I install the traceroute functionality from busybox programmatically"

Comment: @amccormack I edited that. If you know how to achieve this then please help me. I am stuck in this from 5 days.